# How do I draw a non-filled in square. I.e. just the lines?

Tags: svg, path

How do I draw a non-filled in square. I.e. just the lines.

My code currently looks like this

```
   <svg width="500" height="500">

     <path d="M10 10 L100 10 L100 100 L10 100 Z" stroke="black"></path>
  </svg>
```

It draws a solid black square.
In stead of solid black i just want to see the lines.

How do i do that with path?

Using path is a must

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<svg width="500" height="500">

    <path d="M10 10 L100 10 L100 100 L10 100 Z" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
 </svg>
```